# How do I change a gamemode on garrys mod 13

Tags: garrys-mod

I want to change my Garry's mod gamemode to stranded, but unfortunately the only information I've found is either for dedicated servers or port forwarded servers. I've looked up for LAN and the same videos pop up.

How can I change the gamemode on Garry's mod to Garry's mod stranded?

Comment: wait stranded? do you mean standard

Comment: No, he means [stranded: a survival gamemode](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=133364818).

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the version of stranded found on the workshop, then you should be able to find it by clicking sandbox located in the bottom right of your screen whilst on the main menu. If you found stranded in a location other than the steam workshop (eg. http://garrysmod.org), then it is more than likely outdated due to the major changes between Garry's Mod 12 and Garry's Mod 13.

Stranded is not default with Garry's Mod, so if you haven't already acquired it, then you can download it off the workshop (here is the more or less official version http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=133364818).

Answer (score 0):

Download a game-mode and to change it is on the start menu in the bottom right corner (if you can see it change your screen resolution)

Comment: standard btw is called "sandbox" if you didn't know

Answer (score 0):

If you have the gamemode already installed all you need to do is to go to the bottomright of the main menu and change it to the said gamemode and then start the game

Answer (score 0):

The answers here are awful and have NOTHING to do with a dedicated server, the answers provided only apply if you're making a local server on your own computer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/315157)